# Gem creation: run code on installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to create a gem that installs some binaries on "/usr/local/bin". In order to work, I need to run some "cp"/"ln"/"chmod" commands when the user (me) runs `gem install mygem`.

Is there any callback/method that is called at the installation and that I can override it?

---

**UPDATE:**
I found a better way to achieve it: *gemspec* has a section to add binary files on the system. I put the answer below, but I still wonder **how to run code after/before gem installation**.

Answer (score 1):

See this https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/608 you have to run the default task after installation

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to achieve it: ***gemspec*** has a section to add binary files on the system.
Eg:

```
spec.bindir        = "bin"
...
spec.executables << 'your_app'
```

Then, put *your_app* in *bin*.

***PS:*** I'm the OP, but I will not accept this as solution because I still wonder how to run code after/before gem installation.